# codesignal for the smallest code by kotlin

Tags: kotlin

If the list contains the following elements `("a", "b", "a")` then the function should return `0.6666666666666666`,
the percentage of `"a"` appearances in the list.

The returning value should always be between `0.0` and `1.0` if the input is correct.

Also the list should have at least one `"a"` and one `"b"`.

If the list has one incorrect element or more, the function should return -1.0.

Here are some example of incorrect values: `"A"`, `"c"`, `"aa"`, `" "`, `"ab"`, `"بي"`, `"ba"`

```
fun solution(list: MutableList<String>): Double {
  return if ("a" in list && "b" in list) {
    (list.count { it == "a" }.toDouble() / list.size)
  } else {
    -1.0
  }
}
```

When I try it it does not check for `"a"` and `"b"` only but it accepts `"c"` and it should accept `"a"` and `"b"` only.

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking with *"a" in list*, which will return true if at least one entry "a" exists in *list*. No check is made on the other entries. Same for "b". You need to check for each entry if it is "a" or "b".

One way is to count the lowercase "a" and the lowercase "b" and work with these two results. Like this:

```
fun solution(list: List<String>): Double {
  val smallAs = list.count { it.length == 1 && it[0] == 'a' }
  val smallBs = list.count { it.length == 1 && it[0] == 'b' }
  return if (smallAs > 0 && smallBs > 0 && smallAs + smallBs == list.size) {
    smallAs.toDouble() / list.size
  } else {
    -1.0
  }
}
```